# Integrating liveagent chat into a react/webapp

Tags: javascript, liveagent, react

I'm trying to implement a liveagent chat instance that's triggered from within a (React) web app.

I've got the deployment script in my HTML `'https://c.la1-c1-fra.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/48.0/deployment.js` and have a component that is mounted and I can trigger the chat from there.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const SalesForceChat = ({ deploymentID, organizationID, buttonID, instanceID }) => {
    const liveagent = window.liveagent;
    useEffect(() => {
        // Mount unmount
        liveagent.addCustomDetail("ContactFirstName", "Carl");
        liveagent.init(`https://d.${instanceID}.salesforceliveagent.com/chat`, deploymentID, organizationID);
        if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; } window._laq.push(function() {
            liveagent.showWhenOnline(
                buttonID,
                document.getElementById("chatButton")
            );
            liveagent.showWhenOffline(
                buttonID,
                document.getElementById("noChatButton")
            );
        });

        return () => liveagent.disconnect();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>SalesForce Chat</h1>

            <button className="btn btn-primary" id="chatButton" onClick={()=>{liveagent.startChat(buttonID)}}>Chat!</button>

        </div>
    );
};

export default SalesForceChat;
```

This all works but has a few issues I would like to resolve:

1) The button for chat triggered by the `liveagent.showWhenOnline` is referenced by an ID that depends on the page having been loaded. Is there a better way to do this? Is there an event listener I can track to handle this functionality so I could have an online variable that tracks it and updates the UI accordingly?

2) My tab suspended, and when it reawoke the `liveagent.addCustomDetail` fired again and then crashed the app because it was already registered. Is there something I can hook into or check where I can check the keys/values already in the instance? Is it stored somewhere in the window that I can access?

3) Do I need to fully kill and recreate the chat after I have gone through a `liveagent.init => liveagent.disconnect` cycle?

If anybody could help or point me in a direction to help I would greatly appreciate it. In the meantime I will continue to explore other avenues.

Thanks